# WPF Binding Visiblity to Collection Property

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml, binding

I have a ControlTemplate built dynamically from a CollectionViewGroup.

I want it's visibility to be true only when all of it's items have a certain property set to true. I have somewhat accomplished this by:

XAML

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding Path=Items, Converter={StaticResource AllAcceptedToVis}}" Click="Button_ShipmentComplete_Click" Width="150" Margin="100,0,0,0">Complete</Button>
```

C#

```
public class AllAcceptedToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var items = (IEnumerable<object>)value;

        return items.Cast<MyObject>().All(m => m.Accepted) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("AllAcceptedToVisibilityConverter can only be used OneWay.");
    }
}
```

This works, but only when it loads. It does not check for changes after the initial creation, and I suspect because it's bound to a list of addresses (Items) rather than a property, so it actually detects no change in the list of addresses at all (they remain unchanged).

How can I accomplish the above, but have the binding dynamically monitor all Items property changes?

Comment: @KingKing That won't do him any good; the binding is against the **collection instance**, so the converter will only be invoked if and when `Items` is set to a new collection.  The binding engine doesn't know that it should reevaluate the binding if the collection changes, or if some property of an item within the collection changes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are binding against the **collection instance**, so the binding will only reevaluate if and when you assign a *new collection* to `Items`.  Presumably, you are only setting `Items` once, so the converter will only be invoked once.  It will not be invoked when the collection is modified, nor will it be invoked when the items within the collection are modified.  WPF bindings don't support those kinds of 'deep' dependencies, so you will need to find a different approach.

I recommend maintaining a separate property on your view model, e.g., `AllItemsAccepted`, which you can bind to directly.  It will be up to you to listen for additions, removals, and replacements on `Items`, and to listen for property changes on any of the elements within `Items`.  When such a change occurs, you must reevaluate `AllItemsAccepted`.  Don't forget to raise a property change notification so any bindings on `AllItemsAccepted` will be reevaluated.

Note that there *is* a concept of a `MultiBinding` (and `IMultiValueConverter`), but those are only useful if you are binding against a **known, fixed set of values** (e.g., two or more separate properties); they won't help you with a dynamic collection.  I only bring them up to save you from going down a rabbit hole and coming up empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike.

My issue with that is that I have many of these Buttons that are created on the fly, they all have their own set of items (they are essentially a groupstyle for groups of a collection), so I couldn't have one static variable between all of them to decide visibility.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding you though.

Comment: The converter in your question evaluates whether all items are accepted; you just need to evaluate that yourself, put the result in a property somewhere accessible (e.g., alongside `Items`), and keep it up to date.  Basically, do yourself what you expected the binding to do for you.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment but I retracted my vote as I think you are trying to calmly talk over the part that is actually the question, no offense. I just don't want to confuse any other readers of this. To future readers, I believe Mike has misunderstood the question and this is of no value.

Comment: What exactly is it that you think I misunderstood?  There is no way practical way to accomplish what you want using a `Binding`.  If you want to bind against a value that depends on the the state of items in a collection, then you will need to produce that value yourself.  WPF bindings are not that sophisticated.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Then I misunderstood your comment and didn't want to fool anyone else into thinking this was viable. This is a big project I am trying to work this into and I just don't think it's set up for it. The issue is that although I am working with one type of item, it has two seperate grouping styles (depending on an item property), and once within that group I have no individual control over how the group style functions compared to that group's instance of items.